# How can I use multiple mocks of an interface for a Java EE "@Inject private Instance<T> implementations"?

Tags: mockito, java-ee-6

I have an interface:

```
public interface Service {
    void doService();
}
```

And a class:

```
public class ServiceUser {
    @Inject
    @Any
    private Instance<Service> serviceImplementations;

    public void work() {
        serviceImplementations.forEach(service -> service.doService());
    }
}
```

And a testcase:

```
public class ServiceUserTest {
    @Mock
    private Service firstImpl;

    @Mock
    private Service secondImpl;

    @InjectMocks
    private ServiceUser serviceUser;

    @Test
    public void testAllImplementationsCalled() {
          serviceUser.work();

          verify(firstImpl).doService();
          verify(secondImpl).doService();
    }
}
```

When I run the testcase, I get a `NullPointerException` in `ServiceUser`, where on debugging `serviceImplementations` is null. If I create two fields in `ServiceUser` I can get the two instances injected (both mocks are injected, I checked during debugging).

```
public class ServiceUser {
    @Inject
    @Any
    private Instance<Service> serviceImplementations;

    @EJB
    private Service firstImpl;

    @EJB
    private Service secondImpl;

    public void work() {
        serviceImplementations.forEach(service -> service.doService());
    }
}
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, I couldn't find a good existing fake or test double for `Instance<T>`, as in `Instance<Service> serviceInstance = TestingInstance.of(firstImpl, secondImpl);`.

You might want to create one—not using Mockito, but rather as an actual implementation—and test and use it. The interface is relatively small, particularly if you just throw UnsupportedOperationException on the `select` methods, and then you'll have an implementation you can use in all of your test cases.

Because it's not a mock, you would need an alternative to @InjectMocks, though; given the fragility of @InjectMocks as dependencies change, this may not be a bad thing anyway.

Comment: What kind of strategy would you use to inject the `TestingInstance`? (I can think of using reflection myself, but I was wondering if there is a more convenient way.)

Comment: @Timo I favor a package-private constructor, or maybe a static factory method—particularly given that the field is non-final. The temptation to over-encapsulate can make things much harder; instead, treat your test as a first class consumer, and your mocks as first-class replacement implementations they are, and at that point you can design in all the flexibility you need.